# Windows 10, Exessive use of comctl32.dll in .Net 4.0 and up

Tags: c#, .net, dll

I experience slow application (.Net WinForm app) due to filetime to winsxs dll´s version 5.82 and 6.10 of comctl32.dll

Running the application repeatedly loads comctl32.dll, i tried adding a manifest forsing use of v6 of the commom controls, ie comctl32.dll v 6. to no avail. Also tried pinvoke the DLL to try to force use. also to no avail. Applications consists of several projects or modules. I made a simple test application that adds 500 textBox controls to a flowlauoutpanel, dynamically. It gives me on windows 10, 6000+ operations on comctl32.dll. on windows 7 its 2 operations. if i build for .Net 3.5 and below, its also only 2 operations on Windows 10. Can i force the application to load comctl32.dll once or even only a few times instead of several thousands ?  ps. i tried 64bit and 32bit. filetime is a factor 200+

Code (just minimal winforms project)

```
public partial class Form1 : Form 
{ 
    public Form1() 
    { 
        InitializeComponent(); 
        AddTextBoxes(500); 
    }
    private void AddTextBoxes(int number) 
    { 
         for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) 
         { 
             TextBox newBox = new TextBox(); 
             newBox.Width = 30; 
             flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(newBox); 
         }
    } 
}
```

Build for :net 2.0 This is the result in processmonitor:

- 8 total events, filetime : 0.0002639 sek,

Build for .Net 4.0 This is the result in processmonitor:

- 6054 total events, filetime : 0.0931603 sek

.Net 3.5 is not a part of the problem. Only .Net 4 and up.

What can I do to reduce these file events when run in .Net 4.0 on Win10?

Comment: Hoe did you measure that and share your test app as an [mcve]  because I can't repro what you see, at least time spend in comctl32  is for me always around 2% cpu time for my test application

Comment: Code (just minimal winforms project)
'code'
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {

            InitializeComponent();
            AddTextBoxes(500);
        }

        private void AddTextBoxes(int number)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
            {

                TextBox newBox = new TextBox();
                newBox.Width = 30;
                flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(newBox);
            }
        }
    }

Comment: Build for :net 2.0
This is the result in processmonitor:  8 total events, filetime : 0.0002639 sek, 
Build for .Net 4.0
This is the result in processmonitor:  6054 total events, filetime : 0.0931603 sek,

Comment: And..  sry .Net 3.5 is not a part of the problem. Only .Net 4 and up..

Comment: You can [edit] your question to add that information.

Comment: Thanks, i did now..   Did i supply enough information, now with code?, just punk me for more info if nesseseary. i relly need a soultion for this problem.

Comment: Have you tried with a *supported .NET version?*. 4.0 is no longer supported, the earliest supported version is 4.5.2. That's a serious issue, because TLS 1.2 was added in 4.5.2. Now that everyone drops support for SSL and even TLS 1.1, you may end up unable to connect to services. Second, if you have to add hundreds of controls on a form, you have a more serious problem already. You should be looking at virtualization and paging techniques, not trying to load more invisible controls.

Comment: Yes i did try a newer version as stated above. All the way to 4.61. makes no difference. Im already using paging where possible, Design does kind of suck i know but i cannot change the entire design at this moment. it would take > 10.000 hours, With this issue on top, im facing major problems with performance.

Comment: I now activated Microsoft, maybe they can help.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this problem?  We are facing exactly the same problem with one of our larger Winforms applications...

Answer (score 1):

The Problem seems to be the different behavior of the native function **GetModuleHandle** under Windows 10. This function gets called in **System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateParams** in .NET 4 but **not** in .NET 2.
Calling **GetModuleHandle("comctl32.dll")** under Windows 10 results every time in:

```
CreateFile C:\Windows\WinSxS\...\comctl32.dll
QueryBasicInformationFile C:\Windows\WinSxS\...\comctl32.dll
CloseFile C:\Windows\WinSxS\...\comctl32.dll
```

There are no file operations under Windows 7 by calling GetModuleHandle.

Comment: This is interesting observation. Since it looks related to SxS, can it be cured with some manifest?

Comment: @ddbug: Adding a manifest with commmon controls 6.0 changes only behavior of startup: there are no file operations anymore on comctl32.dll v5.82. The main problem doesn't change: every call to GetModuleHandle still opens and queries comctl32.dll v6.0.